# Variables in Google Closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify, google-closure

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

```
(function(){

var somevar = 'somevar';

this.each(function(){
var minify_var = {
  method1: somevar + '1', 
  method2: somevar + '2',
  method3: somevar + '3',
  method4: somevar + '4',
  method5: somevar + '5'
};

alert(minify_var);
});

})();
```

Code like this is minified to:

```
(function(){this.each(function(){alert({method1:"somevar1",method2:"somevar2",method3:"somevar3",method4:"somevar4",method5:"somevar5"})})})();
```

Which is definitely bigger at length (+11 symbols) than:

```
(function(){var a="somevar";this.each(function(){alert({method1:a+"1",method2:a+"2",method3:a+"3",method4:a+"4",method5:a+"5"})})})();
```

The problem is, we had two variables, but got one instead.

Actually it's not bad for a small scripts, but can hurt on a big ones.

First variable is added to make minified code a bit smaller, but google ignores it.

It also ignores most of the other size optimization tricks like this.

Can it be fixed?

This question is about Google Closure, not JavaScript patterns.

Comment: I guess Closure was designed for code following better practices. You should probably write readable code and let it minify it.

Comment: @dystroy it's not a better practice, seems it just merges the variables, which are read-only

Comment: Well, this simplifies the code and avoids useless runtime computation, this looks smart. Premature minification is the other root of all evil...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler assumes that the file will be gzipped when it's served to the user, so it optimizes for the *compressed* file size instead of the uncompressed size.

I tested with two versions of the code.

**Version A** (treating `a` as a global variable prevents it from being automatically concatenated later):

```
(function () {
    a = 'somevar';

    this.each(function () {
        var minify_var = {
            method1: a + '1',
            method2: a + '2',
            method3: a + '3',
            method4: a + '4',
            method5: a + '5'
        };

        alert(minify_var);
    });
})();
```

Resulting minified code:

```
(function(){a="somevar";this.a(function(){alert({b:a+"1",c:a+"2",d:a+"3",e:a+"4",f:a+"5"})})})();
```

Size: 97 bytes (**95** bytes gzipped).

**Version B** (the same as above, but `a` is a local variable so the compiler does its optimizations):

```
(function () {
    var a = 'somevar';

    this.each(function () {
        var minify_var = {
            method1: a + '1',
            method2: a + '2',
            method3: a + '3',
            method4: a + '4',
            method5: a + '5'
        };

        alert(minify_var);
    });
})();
```

Resulting minified code:

```
(function(){this.a(function(){alert({b:"somevar1",c:"somevar2",d:"somevar3",e:"somevar4",f:"somevar5"})})})();
```

Size: 110 bytes (**89** bytes gzipped).

---

So the second version is larger uncompressed, but **when it's gzipped it's smaller** because the variable declaration is gone and gzip compresses repetitive parts to roughly the same space regardless of how long the repeated text is.

Here's an entry from the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size):

> **Closure Compiler inlined all my strings, which made my code size bigger. Why did it do that?**
>
> Most people compare code size by looking at two uncompressed JavaScript files. But that's a misleading way to look at code size, because your JavaScript files should not be served uncompressed. It should be served with gzip compression.
>
> Closure Compiler assumes that you are using gzip compression. If you do not, you should. Configuring your server to gzip your code is one of the most effective and easiest optimizations that you can possibly do. The gzip algorithm works by trying to alias sequences of bytes in an optimal way. Aliasing strings manually almost always makes the compressed code size bigger, because it subverts gzip's own algorithm for aliasing. **So Closure Compiler will (almost) always inline your strings when it can, because that will make your compressed code smaller.**

Comment: "optimizes for the compressed file size" -- observation, or documented?

Comment: @JanDvorak It's common sense because the gzipped version is what counts in reality. I can't find an explicit reference but it can be read between the lines in many places: *"Closure Compiler can even tell when two different variables are never used at the same time, letting both share the same name and ensuring that as many variables as possible use very short names for better gzip compression."* [(1)](http://bit.ly/TzZrb5) *"In most cases smaller code is faster code, since download time is usually the most important speed factor in web applications."* [(2)](http://bit.ly/ZlnToI)

Comment: Ah, here it is: *"Closure Compiler assumes that you are using gzip compression."* https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size

Answer (score -1):

Compilers of all kinds (gcc, g++, jdk, etc) always face these kinds of problems: 
"strive for speed or strive for size"

In this case, closure has taken the speed approach. It recognized that you had a constant variable in many places and rewrote the value directly. Here is what the closure team says about this matter:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#tradeoffs

**Does the compiler make any trade-off between my application's execution speed and download code size?**

Yes. Any optimizing compiler makes trade-offs. Some size optimizations do introduce small speed overheads. However, the Closure Compiler's developers have been careful not to introduce significant additional runtime. Some of the compiler's optimizations even decrease runtime (see next question).

**Does the compiler optimize for speed?**

In most cases smaller code is faster code, since download time is usually the most important speed factor in web applications. Optimizations that reduce redundancies speed up the run time of code as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're misreading the FAQ. It specifically says that they optimize mainly for size, not speed.

Comment: I have read the FAQ, and while in general closure-compiler does optimize for size, in this specific instance, it most certainly does not.

Comment: It certainly does! For the gzipped size, that is. See my answer for details.

Comment: Aha, but that is my point. As far as the _compiler_ is concerned, this is not size optimized.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Repeating the constant results in a file that's 6 bytes smaller. That's certainly size optimization.

Comment: I suppose the smaller file size could be a side effect of speed optimization instead of the other way around, but I highly doubt it. String concatenation is so cheap that it's not worth optimizing for performance's sake only.

Comment: But that size benefit is only obtained when combined with compression. This matter is actually of particular significance to me - we use closure to compile an app which is delivered with an embedded web-server that does not support gzip.
Regardless, based on the FAQ, I think it is fair to say that this inline concatenation is an intentional effort to reduce compressed file size and not some form of performance-based optimization

Comment: Even then you can tell the compiler to not optimize for gzip: *["If you know your client doesn't support gzip, the Java API has an aliasAllStrings option on the CompilerOptions class. Turning this on will make the compiler alias all your strings in the global scope."](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size)* So if you tell the compiler to not optimize for gzip, it won't do the inlining optimization at all.

Comment: And yes, the FAQ says exactly that, which is a contradiction to what you say *("In this case, closure has taken the speed approach.")*

Comment: For us, aliasAllStrings actually doesn't help. It's a bit of a heavy hammer approach and blindly aliases everything...