# Why does Closure Compiler override a short var ref. to a 'this' keyword and restore 'this'?

Tags: javascript, compression, google-closure-compiler

I am testing some code using the Google Closure Compiler with simple optimization, and to my surprise a function such as:

```
window.navigator.detect = function() {
  var t = this,
  a = t.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
  match = /(chrome|webkit|firefox|msie)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(a) ||
  /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(a) ||
  a.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec(a) || [];

  t.ua = match[1] || false;
  t.vers = match[2] || "0";
  if (t.ua) t[match[1]] = true;
  if (match = t.msie)
  t.ie = parseInt(t.vers);//ie main version or false if not IE
  else if (t.chrome)
  t.webkit = true;
  else if (t.webkit)
  t.safari = true;
  //css prefix
  t.pre = t.webkit ? '-webkit-' : t.firefox ? '-moz-' : t.ie > 7 ? '-ms-' : t.opera ? '-o-' : '';
}
window.navigator.detect();
```

Turns into:

```
window.navigator.detect = function() {
  var a = this.userAgent.toLowerCase(), a = /(chrome|webkit|firefox|msie)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(a) || /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(a) || 0 > a.indexOf("compatible") && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec(a) || [];
  this.ua = a[1] || !1;
  this.vers = a[2] || "0";
  this.ua && (this[a[1]] = !0);
  this.msie ? this.ie = parseInt(this.vers) : this.chrome ? this.webkit = !0 : this.webkit && (this.safari = !0);
  this.pre = this.webkit ? "-webkit-" : this.firefox ? "-moz-" : 7 < this.ie ? "-ms-" : this.opera ? "-o-" : ""
};
window.navigator.detect();
```

I wanted to use a smaller 't' variable as reference to 'this' to save some bytes instead of a longer 'this' used 17 times. In this case the Closure Compiler makes my code longer, which is somewhat ironic. Not sure whether this is intended or not. And I don't see anything related in Google's documentation.

Any ideas how to prevent this kind of caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out by myself, with some more googling...
The answer is similar to this issue about Closure Compiler inlining strings: [Variables in Google Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848174/variables-in-google-closure)

And this conundrum on the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size):

> "**Closure Compiler inlined all my strings, which made my code size
> bigger. Why did it do that?** Most people compare code size by looking
> at two uncompressed JavaScript files. But that's a misleading way to
> look at code size, because your JavaScript files should not be served
> uncompressed. It should be served with gzip compression."..." The gzip
> algorithm works by trying to alias sequences of bytes in an optimal
> way. Aliasing strings manually almost always makes the compressed code
> size bigger, because it subverts gzip's own algorithm for aliasing."

I tried passing the 't' var as function argument using: `window.navigator.detect(window.navigator);` and then `window.navigator.detect = function(t){}` which keeps a short 1 character variable. But while it saves 27 bytes on the 'Compiled Size', the 'gzipped size' is actually bigger by 1 byte...

So while it's not entirely about aliasing strings here, the gzip end result is similar, and should be the primary concern in terms of size reduction.